# Scraping data when a parent tag has a child for some element only

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to scrape data from an e-commerce site for a certain product. On the result page, there are 50 products listed. Some products have original prices under them while some have discounted prices with original prices striked-out. The HTML code for that is

for non-discounted products

```
<div class="class-1">
    <span>
        Rs. 7999
    </span>
</div>
```

For discounted product

```
<div class="class-1">
    <span>
        <span class="class-2">
         Rs. 11621
        </span>
        <span class="class-3">
         Rs. 15495
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="class-4">
     (25% OFF)
    </span>
</div>
```

What the result should be?

I want a code that could scroll through the list of products and extract data from `Div[class='class-1]/span` tag for the non-discounted product and where there is a child `span[class='class-2']` present, it should extract data from only that tag and not from the `Span[Class-3]` tag.
Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you clearly, first you need to get a list of products with:

```
products = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="class-1"]')
```

Now, you can iterate thru the list of products and grab the prices as following

```
prices = []
for product in products:
   discount_price = product.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class="class-2"]')
   if(discount_price):
      prices.append(discount_price[0].text)
   else:
       prices.append(product.find_element_by_xpath('./span').text)
```

Explanation:
Per each product I'm checking existence of `//span[@class="class-2"]` child element as you defined.
In case there is such an element, `product.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class="class-2"]')` will return non-empty list of web elements. Not empty list is Boolean `True` in Python so `if` will go.
Otherwise the list is empty and `else` will go.